# Empty field show as error every time I submit form using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I try to make a code for form validation and submission using ajax but when i submit the form it always show me error as empty field.

[image]

index.php

```
<form action="" method="post" id="#user_reg">
<!--printing error or success message -->

   <li>
       <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name"
          <?php 
                 //restoring values
              if(!empty($error)){
                echo "value = ".$firstName;
              }
          ?>
       >
   </li>
   <li>
       <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" placeholder="Last Name"
         <?php 
                 //restoring values
              if(!empty($error)){
                echo "value = ".$lastName;
              }
          ?>
       >
   </li>
   <li>
       <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" placeholder="Username (must be greater than 5 characters)"
        <?php 
                 //restoring values
              if(!empty($error)){
                echo "value = ".$userName;
              }
          ?>
       >
   </li>
   <li>
       <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email"
         <?php 
                 //restoring values
              if(!empty($error)){
                echo "value = ".$email;
              }
          ?>
       >
   </li>
   <li>
       <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password (must be greater than 8 characters)">
   </li>
   <li>
       <input type="password" name="con_password" id="con_password" placeholder=" Confirm Password">
   </li>
   <li>
       <input type="button" name="submit" id="reg" value="Register">
   </li>
</form>
```

ajax

```
$('#reg').click(function(){
//variable for storing post data
var firstName = $('#firstName').val();
var lastName = $('#lastName').val();
var userName = $('#userName').val();
var email = $('#email').val();
var password = $('#password').val();
var con_password = $('#con_password').val();

//making an ajax request

$.ajax({

    url  : "request/register.php",
    type : "POST",
    data : 'firstName='+firstName + '&lastName='+lastName + '&userName='+userName + '&password='+password + '&con_password='+con_password,
    dataType : "text",
    success : function(response,status,http){
        $('#show').html(response);
    },
    error : function(http,status,error){
        alert('server error');
    }

}) })
```

register.php

```
$success = "Submitted"; 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){


    $firstName    =  trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'firstName'    ,FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
    $lastName     =  trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'lastName'     ,FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
    $userName     =  trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'userName'     ,FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
    $email        =  trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email'        ,FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL));
    $password     =  trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password'     ,FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
    $confirm_pass =  trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'con_password' ,FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));


   //checking for empty feilds
    if($firstName == "" || $lastName == "" || $userName == "" || $email == "" || $password == "" || $confirm_pass == ""){
        $error = "Empty Fields";
    }

    //checking username length 

    if(empty($error) && strlen($userName)<=5){
      $error = "Username must be greater than 5 characters";
    }

    //checking for username existence

     if(empty($error) && user_exist($userName)){
        $error = "Username already exist";
     }

    //email validation
     if(empty($error) && !filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
      print_r($_POST);
      $error = "Invalid Email address";
    }

    //checking for email existence

     if(empty($error) && email_exist($email)){
        $error = "Email already exist";
     }

    //checking password length
     if(empty($error) && strlen($password)<=8){
      $error = "Password must be greater than 8 characters";
    }

    //matching confirm password
   if(empty($error) && $password !== $confirm_pass){
      $error = "Password not match";
    }

    if(empty($error)){
      if(user_registration($firstName,$lastName,$userName,$email,md5($password))){
        header("location:index.php?registered");
        exit();
      }else{
        $error = "Something went wrong";
      }
    } }


if(!empty($error)){
      echo "<span class=\"error\" data-icon ='&#xea0f;'>".$error."</span>";
    }
```

Comment: Where is `$('#show')` div ?

Comment: Try $( "form" ).serialize().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your ajax call you not pass email id

```
 data : 'firstName='+firstName + '&lastName='+lastName + '&userName='+userName + '&password='+password + '&con_password='+con_password,
```

so pass email id in ajax call 
use this

```
data : 'firstName='+firstName + '&lastName='+lastName + '&userName='+userName + '&password='+password + '&con_password='+con_password+'&email='+email,
```

i hope it will be helpful